# positioning text using itextSharp in C3

Tags: itext

I am trying to generate a pdf on button click. I am having challenge to design the page. If anybody can help on, how to position the text in particular position.

Say I want my address to in the top right corner and heading in the center.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
private void pdf_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
    svg.ShowDialog();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(svg.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        // Create a Document object
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        // Create a new PdfWrite object, writing the output to a MemoryStream
        // var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);               
        document.Open();
        // First, create our fonts... (For more on working w/fonts in iTextSharp, see: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts
        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, Convert.ToInt32(Font.Bold));
        var AddressFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Convert.ToInt32(Font.Bold));
        var boldTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Convert.ToInt32(Font.Bold));
        var endingMessageFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Convert.ToInt32(Font.Italic));
        var bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12);
        // Add the "" title
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Certificate of Analysis", titleFont));
        // Add Address 
        var text = document.Add(new Paragraph("Abc Company", AddressFont));
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Tel:(xx) xxx-xxxx, (xxx) xxx-xxx", AddressFont));
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Fax: (xxx) xxx-xxx, , AddressFont));
        document.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve what you want.

Currently, you are telling iText to do the layout. If you want to center the text `"Certificate of Analysis"`, then you could change the alignment of the `Paragraph` like this:

```
Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Certificate of Analysis", titleFont);
header.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
document.Add(header);
```

If you want the text `"Abc Company"` to be right-aligned, you can change he alignment like this:

```
Paragraph company = new Paragraph("Abc Company", AddressFont);
company.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
document.Add(company);
```

Of course: when we add `company`, it will start on a new line under `header`. Maybe you want the text to be on the same line.

In that case, why not use a `PdfPTable`?

```
PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(3);
myTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
PdfPCell mydate = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("April 22, 2015", myfont));
mydate.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
myTable.AddCell(mydate);
PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Certificate of Analysis", titleFont));
header.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
header.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
myTable.AddCell(header);
PdfPCell address = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company Address", AddressFont));
address.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
address.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
myTable.AddCell(address);
doc.Add(myTable);
```

Now the available width of your page will be divided in three, the date will be aligned to the left, the header will be centered, and the address will be aligned to the right. Obviously, you can add more data to a `PdfPCell` and more rows to the `PdfPTable`. This is just a simple proof of concept.

Another option, is to add the text at an absolute position (using coordinates). This can be done by using the `ColumnText` object. There are plenty of examples on this in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the direction Bruno. That helps a lot.

Comment: This is just a start. If you go for a `PdfPTable`, you'll probably also want to define different sizes for the columns, adding more than just text (search for *text mode* vs *composite mode*), and so on. The documentation will help you, and if not, feel free to post another question.